# Updating a style trigger in code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML with a StackPanel and various TextBlocks inside it that I'm using as a menu:

```
<StackPanel Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="CornflowerBlue">
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>

<TextBlock Padding="10" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="local:MainWindow.UserList" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        USER LIST
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Padding="10" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">                    
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="local:MainWindow.Exit" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        EXIT
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

And in the code, I have this function:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBlock).Tag = 1;
    //(sender as TextBlock).Tag = "1"; //Or this
}
```

If I set the `Tag` in the XAML, the style is property updated, but this doesn't happen if I set the `Tag` in the code. I've also tried manually changing the `Background`/`Foreground` properties in the code but I'm guessing the XAML style is overwriting it.

I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks the textblock, the background/foreground (or whatever else the style requires) updates as well, 
it's a "Selected" Menu option, but I can't get it working.

Is there any simple way to get this working without having to write a custom control?

Comment: Use the code line where you assign the string "1" to the Tag property. This should work...

Comment: @elgonzo I did but it doesn't work, I left commented because it's one of the things I've tried.

Comment: Hmm, strangely enough your example code works here when i use the code line that assigns the "1" string to the Tag property. I have removed the command bindings, though. Scratching my head...

Comment: You could also try changing your trigger XAML to something like this `<Trigger Property="Tag"> <Trigger.Value><sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32></Trigger.Value> ...` (`sys` is namespace declaration like `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`) and then assigning integer values to Tag should work. But i would prefer assigning a string value to Tag, since the XAML for triggering on an integer looks rather ugly ;) That said, i really have no idea why assigning a string does not work for you... i mean, it should work. Perhaps there is something more going on in your code?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just set up a DataTrigger in your style that sets foreground/background when the textbox has focus? There are actually quite a few ways to implement what you're trying to do, but I'd need a few more specific details as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @elgonzo You're right, I've tried removing the command binding and it worked...

Comment: @MarkFeldman I'm trying to make a menu, when the user clicks an item, I want to change the style to something else so that it looks as a "selected" menu item. I'll try looking in the focus event to see if that works.

Comment: @Daniichi, the desired functionality you describe sound like the behavior of a checkbox (or perhaps radio buttons) or a checkable menu item. Clickable controls such as checkboxes/radio buttons/menu items provide support for commands which are being executed when clicked on them - although it could perhaps be simpler to bind a view-model property to the "IsChecked" property and react to changes in the setter of the view-model property. The "IsChecked" property can also be used by triggers of your style or control template to alter the visual appearance according to its checked/unchecked state.